# Как выполнить две последовательные команды для консоли в при выполенеии команды json файла?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, npm

Как добавить две последовательные команды для консоли в json файл?

Я осваиваю *node.js и NPM*, у меня есть папка **"server"** в которую установлен **http сервер** и **package.json** файл, и в ней же находится папка **"webdir"** с веб страницей.

Я могу запустить веб сервер вручную, или указав путь к нему с командой `node [путь до файла, запускающего сервер]`, но мне нужно чтобы это происходило автоатически по команде `npm start`. И запускаться он должен из папки **"webdir"**, чтобы я сразу мог попасть на мою веб страницу по адресу `localhost:8080`.

Для этого мне нужно написать в консоли две последовательные команды:
1. cd webdir
2. node [путь до файла, запускающего веб сервер]

Какой должен быть синтаксис в **json** файле чтобы команда вводила и исполняла последовательно две эти строчки в консоль?

Вот так выглядит работающий код с одной строчкой:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node (...)/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из простых вариантов - посмотрите на дефолтовый `package.json`, генерируемый командой `npm init`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Знак `&&` позволяет запустить одну команду за другой, если первая выполнена без ошибок. Если использовать `||` то, вторая команда будет выполнена, только если первая вернет ошибку. Это не особенность `npm`, это обычные операции командной строки.

Для более сложных случаев можно вынести последовательность команд в отдельный скрипт, и указать уже его.

Comment: Спасибо большое, почему-то в этом варианте выводится вся строка скрипта комманды в консоли, носервер не запускается...

Comment: Пока рабочий вариант - использовать точку с запятой, но здесь есть проблема: комманды, которые должны выполняться после запуска веб сервера выполняются после его ручного выключения, видимо до тех пор комманда запуска сервера считается не завершенной. && - может быть способом это исправить?

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Покажите как вы записываете обе команды через &&

Comment: Извините, моя ошибка, перепутал сивол. Все работает, спасибо! Правда проблема с запуском команд после активации сервера осталась...

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Если это linux, то используйте знак & на конце команды (после пробела), тогда команда будет запущена, но не будет ожидания её выполнения. Если нужно кроссплатформенное решение, можно посмотреть https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Comment: Нужно кросплатформенное. Спасибо большое за ссылку, буду изучать!